# best software for multicam video production

Tags: software-recommendation

We have records from 30 cameras (couple TBs of video files), which were started almost simultaneously, part of them were action cameras (so no timecode here, and there are gaps because of battery replacement), other part were usual hd cameras with time codes embeded to video files.
All video is 1080p25.

We need to sync all videos together, and then render all 30 sequences after color correction and cutting.I have tried adobe premiere cc, but is was real pain, especially rendering with crushes and other glitches.

Is there any alternative for Premiere?
We have quite recent workstations running windows 7 with consumer video cards (both ati 7970 and nvidia 680 are available), so it will be great if software can do distributed rendering and use gpu. We also have couple of 2 year mac pro, so osx only software can also be of use.

Comment: What do you mean by crushes and other glitches.  Premiere should be pretty stable and reliable if your hardware is.  Is it a) legit and b) fully patched (the OS, Premiere and hardware drivers)?

Comment: I believe hardware is ok, other 3d applications, such as cinema4d are running fine, there are about 5 five computers that we have tried and all give similar results with media encoder: it can trow cpp exception, it cat just stale on some file and do nothing, it can abort encoding with unknown error
last time i tried i have used youtube 480p preset. Also encoding is not very fast, about an hour for 15 minutes of video on i7 3770 with 16gb of ram and gf680.

Comment: something is wrong then, it should not take more than 30 minutes tops for doing that encode in 1080p quality.  480 should be even faster.  I'm running a first gen I7 with a Radeon 6970 and 12gb of RAM and get better performance.  Something is either wrong with either your drivers, your installation media or your assets.

Comment: I have found the problem, sequences were 4 hours long and i needed only 15 minutes, so I have selected all encoding tasks in AME and changed not only encoding options, but time ranges in format dialog, encoding options were applied to all encoding tasks, but time ranges werent!

Comment: No matter what software you use, you might want to invest in server grade hardware.  Used servers with good specs can be had from ebay for under $500

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Premiere is your best option unless you plan on spending a boatload (thousands and thousands) on an Avid system.  I'd suggest working on smaller sets of cameras at a time and then working off the combined feeds.  You can use multicamera editing mode with several cameras at a time, make the best choices out of those and then run each of those sequences in to another multicamera sequence to further resolve them.

The process is going to kind of suck no matter what system you do it on because it is a boatload of synchronous footage to go through.

Answer (score 1):

Lightworks just became another professional option for multicam editing in version 11.5.

And there is a free version.

Answer (score 0):

You could always try PluralEyes by red giant as long as there is some sound it should work, I don't know what your footage is so its a bit hard to say.

PP should work fine same for FCPX.

I normally put them all in my timelines in FCPX export to Pluraleyes do the sync then back into FCPX, baring in mind most of the time mine is between 2-4 cameras tho

Comment: Why use PluralEyes?  You know you can sync multicam clips using audio inside FCPX now, right?  I'm asking because I'm seriously curious about what benefits PluralEyes offers.  I tried it once, but it didn't seem to be much better.

Comment: I found that when using PP or FCPX it was not syncing my footage correctly, this could be down to to much varied footage or audio not being the best on one cam (a bit louder) but when using PE it worked first time

Answer (score 0):

I know this is "consumer" but power director on a windows platform has multicam with audio sync. 4 cameras is pretty easy with a multicam plug in they have. 
you could do up to 100 video tracks syncing by audio. I am sure it would take a super computer to sync though. I have a fairly powerful xeon based system, but the app is I/o bound when running rather than memory or CPU bound. I am not sure, but i blame this on "consumer" level programming. The program was just not architected for "pro level work".

Answer (score -1):

You can also try Sony Vegas Pro (only Windows). It has good multicam features

Answer (score -1):

How about ScreenFlow from http://www.telestream.net/screenflow/overview.htm?

I'm using it right now, but don't know you like it or not or any other software that has good features than this.

Comment: This is too generic of a question. You have to specifically ask what task are you trying with this software that you need help with. As opposed to what are the good features of this software.

Comment: eLouai - ptoukhmer's post is not a question. It's an answer (sort of)